# Handle Google Recaptcha with python requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests, recaptcha

I'm creating a web bot using the requests module. I need to pass through a form that has a recaptcha in it. I have a local website that can generate a g-captcha-response for this recaptcha. I wanted to know if the g-captcha-response was the only post parameter that was necessary in order to get through the recaptcha. If not, what other information do I need to post?

Here's my code:

```
CaptchaKey = # g-captcha-response from my local website

Session = requests.Session()
FormData = {
    'g-captcha-response': CaptchaKey
}
Session.post(SubmitURL, data=FormData)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [reCaptcha documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) gives a pretty good steer here. With Python and requests you'd be looking at something like the following, at its most basic.

```
import requests, json

try:
    content = requests.post(
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
        data={
            'secret': RECAPTCHA_SECRET,
            'response': captcha_response_from_form,
            'remoteip': USER_IP_ADDRESS,
        }
    ).content
except ConnectionError: # Handle fundamental connectivity issues
    # Handle your error state

# Will throw ValueError if we can't parse Google's response
content = json.loads( content )

if not 'success' in content or not content['success']:
    # The reCaptcha hasn't passed...
```